# Transfer Start taking way too long on my ASP.NET API

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, networking

I have a little problem in my ASP.NET API. I have a very simple setup. There is a Server in my fuse box cupboard thingy, running a Ubuntu Server with a MySQL database. I am connecting with it through my ASP.NET API using the local IP-Address (192.168.xxx.xxx), so internet shouldn't be the problem. The endpoint is also very, very simple:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<Organisation>>> Get()
{
    return await _context.Organisations.ToListAsync();
}
```

The internet also can't be the problem, because it is running on my LAN... Does anyone know what the problem could be? There is a screenshot of the timings here below in Postman:

[image: Screenshot of Postman]

As you can see, the problem is at the "Transfer Start" step.

I hope this is enough information for you to help me. Thanks in advance :)

Little note: I have just retried the API a few times and I just got the following error:

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
      An error occurred using the connection to database 'speedytest' on server '192.168.178.46'.
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
      An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'SpeedPlannerApi.DAL.SpeedyPlannerContext'.
      System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
         at MySql.Data.Failover.FailoverManager.AttemptConnection(MySqlConnection connection, String originalConnectionString, String& connectionString, Boolean mySqlPoolManager)
         at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
         at System.Data.Common.DbConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at MySql.Data.Failover.FailoverManager.AttemptConnection(MySqlConnection connection, String originalConnectionString, String& connectionString, Boolean mySqlPoolManager)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at MySql.Data.Failover.FailoverManager.AttemptConnection(MySqlConnection connection, String originalConnectionString, String& connectionString, Boolean mySqlPoolManager)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at SpeedPlannerApi.Controllers.OrganisationController.Get() in /home/jacob/Documents/Projects/SpeedyPlanner Backend/SpeedPlannerApi/Controllers/OrganisationController.cs:line 28
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Just some information, This is also happening in browsers like Firefox.

Comment: I've been investigating the same problem, and I think its a false alarm on the "Transfer start". The request seems to think that it takes ages to start the transfer, and very little time to execute and download, however my stopwatches in my API paint a different picture. I think "Transfer Start" a lot of the time is just the API doing its processing. That certainly is what is happening for me.

Comment: Apparently "so start time is the time required to get the first byte of the response and download time is the time taken to fetch the full data."  That would support my previous statement. Its just how long it takes to start sending data back.